# Is using a multiprocessing pool in Java encouraged? I have this Python code that I am converting to Java

Tags: java, python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Python code - Uses a multiprocessing pool and maps an array of strings. On each item in the array, a partial function is used to call a callback_function:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
p.map(functools.partial(callback_function,
                            arg1 = arg1,
                            arg2 = arg2,
                          ), array_string_items)
```

I am trying to do something similar in Java. I don't see anything in Java API's that is even remotely as simple as the Python code above.

1) Would using threads instead of a processor pool be more encouraged? 
2) If so, how would I go about implementing this?

Thanks

Comment: You could use ThreadPools. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: See `Collection#parallelStream` and `Stream#map`

Comment: Here is a good example: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-pools.html

Comment: @ApolloSoftware great thanks for the link. However, I would also like to know just a general contextual background about why multi-processing isn't as big of a thing, or as available (so it seems) in Java as it is readily-available in Python? What is the disadvantage/advantage about using multi-threading here as opposed to multi-processing as in my Python example above?

Comment: "multi-processing as available as in Python", heh! Check out google results for `python multithreading only one core` query. It is a bit of a pain in Python too, been there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python example looks like this in Java:

```
stringList.parallelStream()
    .map((str) -> callbackFunction.apply(arg1, arg2, str));
```

Assuming `callbackFunction` takes three arguments and you apply constant arg1, arg2 arguments to it to make it partial.

You can define partial function explicitly:

```
int arg1 = 10;
String arg2 = "foo";
Function<String, String> partialFunction = (str) -> callbackFunction.apply(arg1, arg2, str);
```

And then stream processing becomes ridiculously simple:

```
stringList.parallelStream().map(partialFunction);
```

Comment: You say to apply constant arg1 and arg2 arguments to make it a partial. It seems you are applying 'str' as well. Why is that?

Comment: No, `str` is current element of the list, see `(str)` part before callback

Comment: Yes I see that. That totally makes sense I guess I was just wondering if there is a way to do it like a partial in Python, where you don't pass all three arguments in at the same time, you actually give 'default values' for the partial function, and then pass in 'str' separately.

Comment: Of course you can do it, you can define explicit partial function, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577261/partial-function-application-in-java-8 for reference. I will update my answer to be more specific

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: What if the callback function takes like 8 arguments?

Comment: You either pass all 8 directly or create partial with some arguments substituted with constants, similar to my example above with 3 -> 1 arguments.

Answer (score 2):

[Java8 streams](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/) look almost like your example:

```
Integer ageSum = persons
.parallelStream()
.reduce(0,
    (sum, p) -> {
        System.out.format("accumulator: sum=%s; person=%s\n", sum, p);
        return sum += p.age;
    },
    (sum1, sum2) -> {
        System.out.format("combiner: sum1=%s; sum2=%s\n", sum1, sum2);
        return sum1 + sum2;
    });
```

As for custom runnables/callables the solution also seems as simple as in Python to me:

```
List<Callable<Void>> opsList = new ArrayList<>();
opsList.add(someCallable);
// create list of tasks you need to run in parallel...

ExecutorService execSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4); // 4 threads. check out newCachedThreadPool too
try {
    execSvc.invokeAll(opsList);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    execSvc.shutdown();
}
```